# How to test ReactNative Listview item with enzyme

Tags: reactjs, react-native, enzyme, react-native-listview

I am using enzyme to test my component rendering.

What is the usual approach to testing `ListView` items? For instance, in the following example to test that when an item is clicked, it triggers the `onSelect` prop passing the id?

I am currently using `react-native-mock` which means that the `ListView` does not render anything, and I can't separate the item into a separate component as it needs the `onSelect` prop from the parent.

```
export default class extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
           rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
       })
    }
    renderItem = ({id, title}) => {
        const {onSelect} = this.props;
        return <Button onPress={() => onSelect(id)}>{title}</Button>;
    }
    render() {
        const dataSource = this.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.items);
        return (
            <ListView dataSource={dataSource}
                      renderRow={this.renderItem } />)
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>I got this working using</s>

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Settings onSelect={onSelectSpy}  />);
const item = shallow(wrapper.instance().renderItem(itemProps));
```

I found my initial attempt while seeming to work wasn't actually doing what I had expected. I have now split the list itself and the item into separate components.

So for the minimal example in my question.

```
export default class extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
           rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
       })
    }
    renderItem = (rowProps) => {
        const {onSelect} = this.props;
        return <ListViewItem {...rowProps} onSelect={onSelect} />       
    }
    render() {
        const dataSource = this.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.items);
        return (
            <ListView dataSource={dataSource}
                      renderRow={this.renderItem } />)
    }      
}
```

And the listview item

```
//ListViewItem
export default ({id, title, onSelect}) => 
   (<Button onPress={() => onSelect(id)}>{title}</Button);
```

Comment: You forgot closing tag on button element. Thanks for this Tom. Its a great pattern.

Comment: Scratch that this doesn't work because renderSeparator cant spread properties because it doesn't pass params as an object.

Comment: the rowProps are passed as an object? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Comment: I actually dont know what I was doing but it works now... super weird. thanks!